# Excel - VBA Object does not support this property or method - Paste - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

the line that is giving me trouble is ""Sheets(CStr(WS_M.Cells(n, START_C))).Cells(n, START_C).Paste""

this is supposed to find the tab name in column 3 and go to that tab and paste the tab name in that tab.

```
    Const START_C = 3
    Const MAX_TRAN = 1000
    Const START_R = 2
    Const MASTER = "MASTER"

    Sub MOVEDATACORRECTLY()

    Dim WS_M As Worksheet
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS_M = Worksheets(MASTER)

    For M = START_R To (START_R + MAX_TRAN)
        If WS_M.Cells(M, (START_C + 1)) = "" Then Exit For

    Next M

    M = M - 1

    For n = START_R To M
       WS_M.Cells(n, START_C).Copy
       Sheets(CStr(WS_M.Cells(n, START_C))).Cells(n, START_C).Paste      

    Next n

    End Sub
```

Comment: `WS_M.Cells(n, START_C).Copy Sheets(CStr(WS_M.Cells(n, START_C))).Cells(n, START_C)`  No need for a separate paste...

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
For n = START_R To M
       WS_M.Cells(n, START_C).Copy
       Sheets(CStr(WS_M.Cells(n, START_C))).Cells(n, START_C).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
Next n
```

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225606%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for the Excel `Range` object, `Paste` is not in the list of members. There is `PasteSpecial`, however. I haven't experimented with that, but that might also work.

Comment: PasteSpecial is the same as if you select Paste Special when right clicking on a cell - you can choose to paste values or formats etc only. Paste will paste everything

Answer (score 1):

For copying a range of cells in Excel, using `Copy` method makes the `VBA` program easier to crash / or to give inpredictable results.

Suppose during the your procedure copies data from `system clipboard` and user was trying to `store some other to system clipboard!`

Not always, but from users this kind of mistake might happened.

So I always prefer to use a better approach, something like `Swaping the range on the fly`. Here's a small demonstration:

```
Public Sub Sample_Copy_without_Clipboard()
    Dim dRange As Range, iRange As Range
    Set iRange = Range("A1:B3")
    Set dRange = Range("D1:E3")
    dRange.Value = iRange.Value
End Sub
```

### Note: This method works only with unformatted textual data. If not then either use [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams)'s suggestion or [DanM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129164/danm)'s answer.